# android - how to check the data is uploaded and downloaded successfully?

Tags: android

I built the following function to check whether the device is connected to the network.

```
public boolean check_network(){
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
            activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    return isConnected;
}
```

But, there is a chance that the data is not uploaded to the server even though the device is connected to the network. So, how can I check the data is uploaded and downloaded successfully?

Comment: What are you using for your upload?

Answer (score 0):

After uploading, you could attempt to download the data again. If the data is large, you can request just a hash for comparison. I assume that you are also programming the software on the server so that you can add the ability to do this on the server side.

Comment: `int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode != 200) {//fail}`. Should I use this code to determine that the data is not got?

Comment: @KeroroChan That can work for ensuring that the HTTP request was successful. However, that doesn't ensure that the data was transmitted and saved correctly.

Comment: Eg. the original data I supposed to get is "hello", but the actual data I got is "hell". Do you mean that?

Comment: @KeroroChan Yes, that is one possibility.

Comment: So, how can I deal with it?

Comment: Use a hash like I said in my answer.

Comment: can you give a small piece of example ?